# JVM Closing with Java result 255 error

Tags: java, arduino

I write a Java code to receive data from arduino using RXTX Library through COM ports. When Java receiving and printing it in the console if the arduino suddenly removed then JVM closing with error JAVA Result 255. how to catch that error.When arduino suddenly removed it should print "device removed".

```
package arduino.recieve;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

public class NewClass implements SerialPortEventListener {

    SerialPort serialPort = null;

    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = {
        //        "/dev/tty.usbmodem", // Mac OS X
        //        "/dev/usbdev", // Linux
        //        "/dev/tty", // Linux
        //        "/dev/serial", // Linux
        "COM3"};

    private String appName;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private OutputStream output;

    private static final int TIME_OUT = 1000; // Port open timeout
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600; // Arduino serial port

    public boolean initialize() {
        try {
            CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
            Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

            // Enumerate system ports and try connecting to Arduino over each
            //
            System.out.println("Trying:");
            while (portId == null && portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                // Iterate through your host computer's serial port IDs
                //n2
                CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
                System.out.println("   port" + currPortId.getName());
                for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                    if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)
                            || currPortId.getName().startsWith(portName)) {

                        // Try to connect to the Arduino on this port
                        //
                        // Open serial port
                        serialPort = (SerialPort) currPortId.open(appName, TIME_OUT);
                        portId = currPortId;
                        System.out.println("Connected on port" + currPortId.getName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (portId == null || serialPort == null) {
                System.out.println("Oops... Could not connect to Arduino");
                return false;
            }

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // add event listeners
            try {
                serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
                {
                    System.out.println(" Too Many Listeners ");
                }
            }
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

            // Give the Arduino some time
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    //
    // Handle serial port event
    //
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        try {
            switch (oEvent.getEventType()) {
                case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                    if (input == null) {
                        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
                    }
                    String inputLine = input.readLine();
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        NewClass test = new NewClass();
        test.initialize();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several other event types generated by the serial port that you could maybe try and detect to see if one happens when the arudino gets disconnected.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there is a DTR event which would probably be the best indicator that something has gone wrong, but the SerialPort class does have an isDTR() method. You could be checking that periodically and if that goes false, then it probably means you've lost the connection to the arduino.  You could maybe do that check in a separate thread, or perhaps on every CTS change event.

```
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
            serialPort.notifyOnCTS(true);

...

            switch (oEvent.getEventType()) {
                case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                    if (input == null) {
                        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
                    }
                    String inputLine = input.readLine();
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                    break;

                case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
                    if (!serialPort.isDTR()) {
                      // do something
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Probably having a small worker thread that just checks DTR status would be a better solution though.